# math/logic character \exists renders OK in editor, but faults when compiling

Tags: math-mode, symbols, lyx

The fault message below:

> lyx could not find command for character "$\exists$" (code point 0*2203)

This character renders OK in lyx editor, I pick it from lyx math miscellaneous, it's the first character of second row in that category.

[image]

I try solve this by switch encoding to `UTF8` but no luck there. please help many thanks

thx guys, problem solved, what I did is install amsmath package in miktex package manager, and reconfigure lyx.

Comment: I have no error in TeXnicCenter.  Maybe you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Yes, a [LyX minimal example](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample)  would be nice as well

Comment: thx guys, problem solved, what I did is install amsmath package in miktex package manager, and reconfigure lyx.